# What's the most idiomatic way in Scala to pattern match on a Seq holding enum values converted to strings?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, switch-statement, scala-collections

I'm trying to match an enum value converted to a string held in a collection. Here's the code:

```
object Foo extends Enumeration {
    val ONE = Value("ONE")
    val TWO = Value("TWO")
}

def check(seq: Seq[String]): Unit = seq match {
    case Seq(Foo.ONE.toString) => println("match")
    case _ => println("no match")
}
```

This results in a compilation error:

```
error: stable identifier required, but Foo.ONE.toString found.
           case Seq(Foo.ONE.toString) => println("match")
```

What is the proper way to use my Foo enumerated values as elements of my pattern matching case statements?

Comment: You cannot apply any function inside pattern (there `.toString`).

Comment: Do you want to find out if _all_ elements of the `Seq()` are `Foo` value strings, or simply _any_ of them?  Do you need to report which elements match, or is it simply boolean (i.e. match found/not found)?

Comment: @cchantep nailed it on the head, I should have been matching on `case Seq(Foo.ONE)`. Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the response from @cchantep, which was to avoid calling `.toString` inside the pattern match and implement the `check` method like so:

```
def check(seq: Seq[Foo.Value]): Unit = seq match {
  case Seq(Foo.ONE) => println("match")
  case _ => println("no match")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Map it back to the enum first:

```
import scala.util.Try

val enumSeq = seq map (x => Try(Foo.withName(x)))
```

Then you can either filter out the `Failure`s or match on `Seq(Success(ONE))`, `Seq(Success(ONE))`, ..., `Seq(Failure)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(seq: Seq[String]): Unit = seq match {
  case Seq(s @ _) if s == Foo.ONE.toString => println("match")
  case _ => println("no match")
}
```